# How to hide the numbering of some pages and then continue?

Tags: numbering, page-numbering

In document class "book", I have used the normal page numbering. On the other hand, I would like to hide the numbering of the first five pages of the book and after these 5 pages, the page numbering starts from page 6. How can I do it?
Thank you.

Comment: See `\thispagestyle{empty}` for temporary removal of page numbering, or `\pagestyle{empty}` to make it the norm going forward (until later reversed).

Comment: Use `\pagestyle`'s as usual.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes an answer, sir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, `\pagestyle{}` is used to indicate whether a page number should be present.  Saying `\pagestyle{empty}` suppresses the page numbering, whereas, for example, `\pagestyle{plain}` supplies it.  One may change from one style to another as one goes.

There is also the `\thispagestyle{}` macro for applying a page style for a single page only.

Interestingly, I found in the `book` document class, which the OP cites, there is a tendency to place a page number on the first page of a chapter, even if the page style is `empty`.  In addition, the `\chapter` is always set to start on an odd page.  Thus, to accomplish the specifics of the OP's request, to get *exactly* 5 unnumbered pages, followed by the book beginning its numbering on page 6, a few unnatural gyrations were required:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagestyle{empty}
\chapter{Chapter the First}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[1-11]
\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter{Chapter the Second}
\pagestyle{plain}
\lipsum[1-8]
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]